# Page layout not updating when ajax is called

Tags: javascript, php

Hi im sure im doing something stupid that I cant figure out.

I have a ajax function that recall the page to alter its HTML, however the html layout is not changing.

Javascript:

```
var htpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "cart.php";
    var val = "extra=" + id;
    htpr.open("POST", url, true);
    htpr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    htpr.onreadystatechange = function () {
};
htpr.send(val);
```

PHP

```
$delTotal = $delTotal + $extra_delivery_price;
if(isset($_POST["extra"])){
    echo "test";
    $val = $_POST["extra"];
    if($val === "Europe"){
        $delTotal = $delTotal + 5;
    }else if($val === "Zone1"){
        $delTotal = $delTotal + 11;
    }else if($val === "Zone2"){
        $delTotal = $delTotal + 25;
    }
}

$val = '
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" id="shipping_1" value="'.$delTotal.'">

<p1>Delivery cost: £$delTotal</p1><br>';
```

HTML

```
<?php echo $val;?>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Well its meant to change the Delivery Cost price, but its not.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you are outputting the $val after the ajax is called? AJAX?

Comment: Its output before Ajax once page is first loaded, if user click a check box, ajax function is executed, which recalls same file. where PHP changes $deltotal value and store again to HTML. maybe i need to some what refresh the page? but then that would refresh the value to its original price

Comment: I checked the console and the new value is there. its just not showing on page